# List of tuples c++

Tags: c++, tuples

I'm a novice in C++ and I would like to know if it's possible to write this C# declaration of tuple in C++ please.

```
public List<Tuple<int, double>> [] tab;
```

I don't know what to declare in my .h file and in my .cpp

Thanks for your help

Comment: `std::list<std::tuple<int, double>> tab;`

Comment: Note for adapting the answers: C#'s `List<>` is like C++'s `std::vector`, not `std::list` (that's `LinkedList<>`).

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <list>
#include <tuple>

std::list<std::tuple<int, double>> tab;
```

`<tuple>` is a C++11 addition I believe. If you only need two types in your tuple, you can also use `std::pair` in `<utility>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
std::list<std::pair<int, double> > tab;
```

Or as an array of lists:

```
std::list<std::pair<int, double> > tab[26];
```